# Should I use wpdb prepare?

Tags: plugin-development, mysql, wpdb

I'm new to SQL and am wondering if I need to use `wpdb->prepare` for the following query to a table I've created

```
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_table";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tablename . " ORDER BY date_created DESC";
$resulst = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
```

Do I need to use `prepare` here? How would I do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's best practice to always use `prepare` but the main use of it is to prevent against SQL injection attacks, and since there is no input from the users/visitors or they can't effect the query then that is not an issue in your current example.

But like I said before it's best practice to use it and once you start using it you never stop, so in your example you can use it like so:

```
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_table";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY date_created DESC",$tablename );
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
```

to read more about how to use it head to [**the codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

Comment: Hi @Bainternet, thanks for such a clear explanation - for some reason when I try your code it returns an empty array. I've checked and doubled checked for typos. If I do the unprepared query I get the array. I don't understand why it's not working..!

Comment: Odd. I've tried using the same code with another query: `$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_table";
$concert_id = 1;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tablename . " WHERE concert_id = %d LIMIT 1;";

$prep_sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $concert_id );

$get_concerts = $wpdb->get_results( $prep_sql , ARRAY_A );`

And it works great! Not sure why that would be. But I get it now in any case!

Comment: Enclosing the *table name* in *single quotes* will not work. The normal escaping is with backticks, so your query should end up looking like this: `SELECT * FROM \`wp_my_custom_table\``. You can enable double quote support, but then it would have to look like this: `SELECT * FROM "wp_my_custom_table"`.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. Why you should escape when function already escapes everything? You think Wordpress will decide to remove escaping from core? ALso there is no point to escape table name :) because it's hardcoded and you know it's ok. I kno this is just example but anyways dont escape table names, i have issues when using prepare with table names it adds backticks and SQL trows error.

Comment: @Tommixoft If you read the answer again you'll see that you actually say the same thing as I said, and that the table name is an example.

Comment: Can you support the assertion that *it's best practice*?  Seems odd (as in not best practice) to use a function that is unnecessary and expects 2+ parameters in this case....

Comment: Ahhh the answer is from 2011!!! If you accept input from the user to the query then yes its always  *best practice*.

Answer (score 1):

When you use prepare it is protecting the code from SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Here is the code you need to modify for using `prepare()`;

```
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "my_custom_table";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$tablename} ORDER BY date_created DESC");
$resulst = $wpdb->get_results( $sql , ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: Just because you use `prepare()` the code is not automatically protected against SQL injections. Your code might suggest that `$tablename` is protected against SQL injections because it is used in `prepare` which is not the case, because it is not provided via the arguments. In this case that is not a problem, because the content of `$tablename` is safe, but I think it would be good to clearify that.

Comment: Yes. This answer is wrong and dangerously misleading I would say. You've called `prepare` in a way which does not in fact protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

In your case is not possible [SQL injection attack](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Your code don't need additional protection because don't use user input like: post, get, request, cookie.

Don't use complicated function when are not necessary to save server resources.