# $wpdb->insert Giving duplicates

Tags: database, wpdb, duplicates

I'm getting duplicate entries with this, how can I fix it please?

```
<?php

echo "Month". $_POST["Month"];

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
$wpdb->print_error(); 

$wpdb->insert( 
    'church', 
    array( 
        'Firstname' => $_POST["Firstname"],
        'Surname' => $_POST["Surname"],
    'Month' => $_POST["Month"],
    'Day' => $_POST["Day"],
    'Email Address' => $_POST["Email"],
    'Mobile Number' => $_POST["Number"]
)
);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing that prevent duplicates here.

When you create the table `'church'` is a good idea set a `UNIQUE` sql index for field email, in this way you can rely on email address to preventing duplicate entries.

As a generic PHP good practice, you should check the existence of a a variable before using it, using `isset` function:

```
/* If $_POST['email'] is setted and it is a valid email address */
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  global $wpdb;
  $exists = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'church' WHERE email = %s", $_POST['email']
  ) );

  if ( ! $exists ) {
    /* Your insert code here */
  }

}
```

P.S. Is also a good idea prepend the WordPress table prefix in front of custom table names.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$table_user = $wpdb->prefix . 'user';
$email = $_POST['email'];
// first check if data exists with select query
$datum = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_user WHERE email= '".$email."'");
if($wpdb->num_rows > 0) {
echo "result exists";
}
// if not exist in the database then insert it
else{
$result = $wpdb->insert( 
 $table_token, 
 array( 
    'Firstname' => $_POST["Firstname"],
    'Surname' => $_POST["Surname"],
'Month' => $_POST["Month"],
'Day' => $_POST["Day"],
'Email Address' => $_POST["Email"],
'Mobile Number' => $_POST["Number"]
 )
 );
}
```

Comment: Please prefer usage of `$wpdb->prepare`

Comment: It would be gret if you could explain the code in addition to posting it.

Comment: why i use $wpdb->prepare?above code works for me.Please describe me about prepare

Comment: Even though it works it's not a good practice, check [$wpdb->prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16925/43098)